# jcombobox - drop down sheet size

Tags: swing, jcombobox

I want to control the size of the sheet that opens down when I press the down arrow button in JComboBox,
I want it to display much more options 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `setMaximumRowCount()` to display as many rows as you want in the popup.